# Karate - How to validate output with multiple templates?

Tags: karate

Is there any way to validate output of a request with one of multiple templates?
for example:

```
{  
   "pendingInvitesCount":#number,
   "acceptedInvitesCount":#number,
   "rejectedInvitesCount":#number
}
```

or

```
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really recommended as testing best practice, but this should give you some ideas:

```
* def actual = []
* def expected = (actual.size() == 0 ? '#[0]' : { a: '#number', b: '#number' })
* match actual == expected
```